# Meteor.logout() and Meteor.call() too slow

Tags: meteor

I have a web app. I am living a problem about time of Meteor.logout() and Meteor.call(). When i meteor.logout(), it takes time between about 30-40 sec. Same for Meteor.call() as well. About 200-250 clients use this system on the same time.

if a client see about 100-200 items his on app screen this delay time is so much. but 10-20 items, it's a little well. we get data every 5-10 sec as different times each others on these items. I mean, live screen.

I don't get this problem when i work this system on diffrent port with same code and same database by the way just use only me.

I can't figure it. What can be reason it. I need your ideas and help.

Comment: Which OS? Which port for meteor?

Comment: It'll be tricky to assess without knowing in some detail what you are doing. Can you share the call to `Meteor.logout()` The first thing I'd check is if this is actually taking long to log out or taking long to do whatever action is next. You could try to figure that out by using the callback in the logout function. My gut feeling with poor performance on a busy system would be to check slow running calls on the database or the server. Do you trigger something that keeps running and is not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

While the collection update process is performed from one side, the meteor publish process is performed from the other side. As the number of clients increases, the server becomes unresponsive. I solved it with Mongodb oplog feature.

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: could you provide more details

Comment: Meteor subscriptions and puıblications try to read data same table and other proccess try to write same table. Meteor suubscription makes it more diffcult. Because it trying read every writing. Mongo oplog saves us from this trouble. You can find more details for this issue below link.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/

Answer (score 1):

The logout function waits for a callback form the server, there is something wrong with the way you have configured your server.

Run the same code on another machine, it should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.unblock() in every method and publications.
By default, Meteor process requests one by one, it will queue all the requests coming, if one is processing.

This may be due to the reason that some of the functions doing some bigger functionalities will be requiring more time and all other request to the server have to wait till it ends.

You need to simply place this.unblock() at the starting of every method and publications and it will not block your requests.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons. 
There could be unsubscription of collections, which means client and server exchange the list of id's which are being unsubscribed.

You many have reactive UI, which suddenly gets overwhelmed with the amount of data that is being transferred and needs to update itself. (example angular digest cycle always runs after meteor sub/unsub)

Chrome Inspector - Network websocket frame is your best tool understand how soon Meteor logout fires and and if there are any messages being passed back and forth before server retutns the result of logout request.

You may also use this.unblock() feature in subscribe. This way your subscritption run parallelly and don't block each other